# What datatype to chose for time in Microsoft SQL Server Import Export Wizard?

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

I am importing a csv file using the import and export wizard for microsoft sql server. One of my columns contain data called 'utcsec', which I believe is the utc time zone in seconds. The numbers are integers with range 14400-71995, so I believe it might be seconds passed from 00:00:00 in that timezone.

Using the import export wizard, if I don't change the datatype, it will be varchar, so I want to change it. But I don't know which of the many posibilities for time/date I should choose??

Comment: Do *you* know what times these values are meant to represent? You say you believe it's seconds from 00:00, but do you have any way to verify that conjecture? First, make sure you understand your data.

Comment: I am almost 100% certain that it is as written. So my question is if utcsec is of the format specified, which data type should I use?

Comment: Sounds like an excellent question for the person sending you the data.